# How to display mat-spinner progress bar on top of modal popup?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have mat-spinner progress bar and the CSS for that has been set in style.css since I'm using it across all components. In a particular component I have a modal popup and I want to display a progress bar on top of that. But my CSS doesnt seem to work. Please help with this.

Current CSS in style.css for progress bar is

```
.loading-div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

CSS for modal

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 15%;
  top: 2%;
  width :930px;
  height: 630px;
  z-index: 80;

 }

 .modal-body {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  height :630px;
  width :930px; 
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: auto;

}

.modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 900; 
}
```

What should be the z-index such that I  can display progress bar on top of modal body?

Comment: Could you add your html please

Comment: I had missed to add the spinner div inside modal . Fixed it